# Removing like button from fb:comments

Tags: facebook

i just made new project on facebook using i-frame.i have put fb:comments on my application but the problem is like button with connect parts.I have tried to hide like button from css but could not success.Is there any way to hide?
Thanks

Comment: some code of what you tried, will be more useful to answer you.

Answer (score 0):

in your custom css, you need the following:

```
div.like{visibility:hidden;height:0px;}
```

also works without div (.like{...})

you may have to give your css file a version flag to prevent it from being cached, like this:

```
css="http://www.yourdomain.com/.../facebook.css?38"
```

i just don´t know if it is allowed to hide the like button like this...

Comment: I would rather use `display:none;` and it SHOULD work, I tried in firebug directly...

Comment: yeah, thank you! i tried it, and it works fine. obviously an even better solution :)